# How to solve 'unexpected end of file' error while unziping file in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, marshalling

I am trying to load data from marshalled and gzipped file in Ruby under Windows 10. This file is so called index file and its name is specs.4.8.gz
. I have already tried to load this into variable with following code

```
testdata = Gem.gunzip(File.read('C:\Users\me\Downloads\specs.4.8.gz'))
```

While executing this code I am getting error:

```
#<Zlib::GzipFile::Error: unexpected end of file>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: The file is probably corrupted. Are you able to uncompress it using any other tool?

Comment: I doubt it is corrupted, because it comes from offiical rubygems.org repository. And yes, I can uncompress it manually with WinRar for example

Comment: Since this is a publicly accessible file (from rubygems), can you share what the file actually is? That way, hopefully someone will be able to *reproduce* the problem and help diagnose the solution.

Comment: Did you try `binread` instead of `read`?

Comment: Yes, @Casper is right: `File#read` reads the content as UTF-8, stopping at the first `\0` byte. Setting the encoding to ASCII (or using `File#binread`) would do.

Comment: Issue solved by changing 'read' method to 'binread'. Thanks guys!